How to add new sheet with template in Phpspreadsheet?
I create a sheet and populate it form an array
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex(0);
$worksheet = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, $name);
$spreadsheet->addSheet($worksheet, 0);
$worksheet->fromArray($data);


Now, i want to add a second sheet from a template stored in https://mysite.it/template/ named "template_XXX.xlsx"
How Can I do?
I try
$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = public_path('template_XXX.xlsx');

$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

